# .htaccess make subdirectory root for domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to use htaccess to make a subdirectory the root for an additional domain. I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?thedrive.co$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?thedrive.co$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ test/index.php [L]
```

It works great and hides the 'test' directory in the URL. But, when a file in a subdirectory is requested it shows the 'test' directory. For example, instead of thedrive.co/somefolder it shows thedrive.co/test/somefolder.

How can I get it to not display that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a 301 rule right at the top below `RewriteEngine on` line:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?radioreformation\.co$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+radioreformation.com/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?radioreformation.co$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/radioreformation.com/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /radioreformation.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?radioreformation.co$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ radioreformation.com/index.php [L]
```

This will redirect `thedrive.co/test/somefolder` to `thedrive.co/somefolder`

Comment: Works great when I test it, but when I deploy it on my AWS ELB application I get a 500 error. Any ideas why?

Comment: I will need to know actual error text from error.log for this.

Comment: It looks like this is the error: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Comment: Hmm all the internal redirect rules were all existing rules. What URL did cause this and what is location of .htaccess?

Comment: radioreformation.com is the one I'm trying. The error occurs when you try to go to radioreformation.com/indexb.php
The .htaccess file is above the radioreformation.com folder
Here is the contents of the .htaccess file: http://radioreformation.com/htaccess.txt

Comment: It seems that going to the next directory is the problem. The htaccess.txt file is actually above the radioreformation.com directory. By using the default instance url, it works...http://ondemandapi.elasticbeanstalk.com/radioreformation.com/indexb.php

Comment: Ok for testing rename .htaccess to something else and then retry.

Comment: Okay, the .htaccess is gone. This now makes the files accessible at http://radioreformation.com/radioreformation.com

Comment: ok take .htacccess from my updated answer and then try. (Replace your existing content with this)

Comment: Great, that works! Would I add the rules again to make it work on radioreformation.com as well as radioreformation.co?

Comment: yes but make sure that directory name is correct as you had `/test/` left somewhere.